# Appending to a dynamic list name with dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am hoping to get some help on a python coding road block that I am running in to. 
The task at hand is to sort out a thousands of lines of CSVs in to a group of lists. My CSV is 2 columns. 1st column is PC name. the second column is building.
I could use Excel filtering but looking at potentially 900+ lists(of buildings), with 10k+ PCs to sort and assign, this is going to pose a big challenge with no excel automation. 
So I turned to Python. I am quite rusty since the last time I touched it was 8 years ago. My thoughts were that:
1) I could make the reference the buildings a big collection of lists that I declare at the beginning.

```
Bldng1[]
Bldng2[]
Bldng3[]
```

2) I can export the 2 column CSV that contains the first column as the PC and second column as the building in to  a Python dictionary JSON format.
myPCs={
    "PC1": "Bldng1",
    "PC2": "Bldng2",
    "PC3": "Bldng1",
    "PC4": "Bldng1",
    "PC5": "Bldng3",

}

3) Have a for loop iterate through the dictionary.

for pcs in my_PCs:
    bldng=myPCs[pcs] #essentially get the building name in to variable
    print('Building name',bldng) # to verify I have the correct name

But I can't figure out how to now append the PC name to the building list as the building and PC name will change for every iteration. 
I tried:

bldng.append=['pcs']

thinking that the variable would be populated with the building name but that didn't work.
Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong or what I would need to to? I'd really hate to do excel macros and and would love to just improve on my Python skills.

Basically...
I have an set of empty lists

```
Bldng1[]
Bldng2[]
Bldng3[]
#A dictionary
myPCs={
"PC1": "Bldng1",
"PC2": "Bldng2",
"PC3": "Bldng1",
"PC4": "Bldng1",
"PC5": "Bldng3",
}
#And I want to achieve this:
Bldng1['PC1','PC3',"PC4']
Bldng2['PC2']
Bldng3['PC5']
```

Thank you in advance!!
I have tried googling and trying suggested methods but couldn't find a solution to fit my needs

Code below:

```
Bldng1[]
Bldng2[]
Bldng3[]
    myPCs={
    "PC1": "Bldng1",
    "PC2": "Bldng2",
    "PC3": "Bldng1",
    "PC4": "Bldng1",
    "PC5": "Bldng3",
}


    for pcs in my_PCs:
        bldng=myPCs[pcs]
        bldng.append=['pcs']


Error
bldng.append=['pcs']
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `bldng.append` line has incorrect syntax. `append` is a function you call with the value to be appended:

```python
bldng.append(value)
```

In your `for` loop, you're only iterating over the keys of the `myPCs` dictionary. What you want are the values from `myPCs`. So, using that with the append function would look like this:

```python
for key, value in myPCs.items():
    bldng.append(value)
```

Which would give you these values for `bldng`:

```python
bldng == ["Bldng1", "Bldng2", "Bldng1"]
```

Comment: Actually, I do want to be iterating over the keys right? I'm trying to go over each item key:value (PC:bldng) entry in the dictionary. Then, use the bldng=myPCs[pcs] to get the building info from each entry. Then make a decision on which building list to add it to. Hence, I will need to find a way to dynamically get the building name to reference the list which will have an identical name and append the PC name to that list. Does that make sense....?

Comment: The for-loop example I wrote above gives you access to each `key` and `value` in the `myPCs` dict. You can find it in the code block that looks like this: `for key, value in myPCs.items(): ...`

Answer (score 0):

I kept fiddling till i somehow got it to work. I can't find the link for it now, but the solution for another user suggested creating a dictionary for the set of lists which would allow me to then append easily.

```
bldngs={
"Bldng1":[],
"Bldng2":[],
"Bldng3":[]
}

myPCs={
    "PC1": "Bldng1",
    "PC2": "Bldng2",
    "PC3": "Bldng1",
    "PC4": "Bldng1",
    "PC5": "Bldng3",
}


for pcs in myPCs:
    print('this is the pc',pcs)
    bldng=myPCs[pcs]
    print('this is the building',bldng)
    bldngs[bldng].append(pcs)

print(bldngs)
```